# Swift Correct calculation of time as a proportion of day

Tags: swift, date, swift5

I am trying to calculate the proportion of a day that a specific time equates to.  For example, 06:00 is 0.25, 18:00 is 0.75 etc.

I am evaluating a series of dates of Date type, which were created in timeZone = "GMT".  The routine below works fine.  However when I evaluate a time after 23:00 for dates in DST, then the calculation goes wrong, as the time is evaluated as the next day (e.g. 23:08 is evaluated as 00:08)

Is there any way that I can recognise when the move from GMT to DST takes the date into the next day?  I can then adjust the calculation accordingly.

My function for determining the proportion that the input time represents is:

```
func getTimeAsProportionOfDay(time: Date) -> Double {
    //calculates the amount of day, between 0 and 1 given the input date

    let calendar =  Calendar.current
    let hours = calendar.component(.hour, from: time)
    let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: time)
    let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: time)
    let totalSeconds = Double(hours * 60 * 60 + minutes * 60 + seconds)

    return Double(totalSeconds) / Double(secondsInDay)
}
```

Also, I'm aware that my constant of secondsInDay (= 24*60*60) may not be technically correct but I'm not sure what system constant to replace it with.

Thanks.

Comment: Some days only have 23 hours. What is your plan for those?

Comment: What I’m trying to establish is whether you are after literal truth or numeric simplicity.

Comment: Matt, the 23 hour days (luckily) resolve themselves.  On your second point, literal truth I think, as in any given day, if the time that I want to evaluate falls outside of that day, then it should be ignored as the proportion > 1.  However, I can't find a way to exclude these days or evaluate to > 1 and then ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need get the day after the original date and subtract a second. Then calculate the number of seconds in that date using calendar method

```
func ordinality(of smaller: Calendar.Component, in larger: Calendar.Component, for date: Date) -> Int?
```

You can make your life easier with some helpers

```
extension Date {
    var dayAfter: Date { Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: noon)!}
    var noon: Date { Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)! }
    var startOfDay: Date { Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: self) }
    var endOfDay: Date { Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .init(second: -1), to: dayAfter.startOfDay)! }
}
```

---

Testing the endOfDay

```
Date().endOfDay  // "Feb 7, 2020 at 11:59 PM"
```

And your method:

```
func getTimeAsProportionOfDay(time: Date) -> Double {
    // discarding the fractional seconds
    let time = Calendar.current.date(bySetting: .nanosecond, value: 0, of: time)!
    return Double(Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .second, in: .day, for: time)!-1) /
        Double(Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .second, in: .day, for: time.endOfDay)!-1)
}
```

Playground testing:

```
let date = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2020, month: 2, day: 7, hour: 23, minute: 08).date!
date.endOfDay
let result = getTimeAsProportionOfDay(time: date)  // 0.9639000451394113
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but in my function, I actually want to ignore the times which have been moved into the next day by DST.  So, for example, 23:08 on 25, March 2020 (in UK this is still GMT) gets evaluated as 0.9639000... but 23:08 GMT on 26 April 2020 (which in DST is 00:08 on 27 April 2020) is identified as in the next day and I can return a value of 1.

Comment: I can post it using UTC time if you want

Comment: For context, I am using the proportion of day to create a gradient representing the different qualities of light during a given day.  The times i am evaluating are the various astronomical states of the day.  Therefore, if an astronomical event occurs at say 23:08 BST on a date where DST is in effect, then the event technically belongs to the following day and can be ignored for the gradient calculation.

Comment: So 23:08 will be the end of day and should return 1? So you are going to provide the end of the day to your method?

Comment: any time from 23:00 GMT to 23:59 GMT should return 1, but only during DST when, as far as I can make out, the dates in any expressions evaluate to 00:00 DST to 00:59 DST on the following day.  i.e. I want to ignore times (or give them a default output of 1) that have shifted to the next day because of DST, but I can't figure out a way to identify them.   Dates are a bit new to me, wonderful but new!

Comment: Can you show you actual input and desired output in your question. Please take a look at how to provide a [mcve]

Comment: If you are getting the info from a server show the json response

Comment: @JimBurke i suggest you to first convert or your data to UTC, or some "fixed frame time" model where one day is fixed amount of time units.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, I would do something like this:

```
let date = Date()

var dayStart = Date()
var dayDuration: TimeInterval = 0

Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .day, start: &dayStart, interval: &dayDuration, for: date)

let timeInterval = date.timeIntervalSince(dayStart)
let percentage = timeInterval / dayDuration

print(percentage)
```

Comment: I've tried this in playground and it gives the same result - it evaluates GMT 23:08 as the proportion that 8 mins has (i.e. 0.0055555....).

Comment: What I actually want to do is to determine when a time is shown as the next day.  e.g. when I process the time of 23:08 GMT on 25 April, 2020 and it is evaluated as the DST date of 00:08 on 26, April 2020 by my code then this is a special case and I want to handle it.

Comment: You should explain the real goal, as the spec is unclear. Or improve the spec!

Answer (score 0):

All, thanks for your help.  I think I have found a solution to this by using a fixed start of day to compare against.

```
func getTimeAsProportionOfDay(time: Date) -> Double {
    //calculates the amount of day, between 0 and 1 given the input date


    if Int(time.timeIntervalSince(tides.tideDate)) > secondsInDay { //time has been moved to next day by BST change) so return 1 for gradient
        return 1.0
    } else {/// this was my original code
        let calendar =  Calendar.current
        let hours = calendar.component(.hour, from: time)
        let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: time)
        let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: time)
        let totalSeconds = Double(hours * 60 * 60 + minutes * 60 + seconds)

        return Double(totalSeconds) / Double(secondsInDay)
    }
}
```